# jQuery event handler for input range on dynamic input (while sliding)

Tags: jquery, slider, range, listener, handler

I have a dynamic `input[type="range"]` that I need to create a listener for. I understand I can use `.on('change', 'trigger', function(){})` however this only triggers when the value changes (released). I'm looking for an event handler that updates while sliding.

I know I can do
`$selector.slide(options);` however I want to add the slide handler to dynamic elements.

`$selector.on('I_DONT_KNOW', 'input[type="range"], function(){});`

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, use mousemove

```
$elementInDom.on('mousemove', 'dyanmicTrigger', function(){ console.log('yay'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can update by sliding by using the **oninput event**.
put oninput="yourFunction()"